# Postfix - How to parse bounced message

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I'm very new to Postfix. I tried to google about how to handle bounced messages for two days but my question is not anserwed.

I want to handle bounced messages with an external program, and AFAIK I can do with these steps:

1. Configure main.cf with transport_maps properties

   transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
2. List item

   root@mail.domain.com bounce-pipe:
3. Configure master.cf

   bounce-pipe unix - n n - - pipe user=bounce argv=/etc/postfix/mailpipe.py
4. Create python/ruby script to parse bounced messages with 3rd party lib

It seems that the script is called when receiving a message.
For example, I sent an email to non-existence (i.e non-exitence@gmail.com) and then I got this information in console

```
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:52 mail postfix/pickup[1897]: DEB292A16D9: uid=0 from=<root>
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:52 mail postfix/cleanup[1955]: DEB292A16D9: message-id=<20171214021552.DEB292A16D9@mail.domain.com>
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:52 mail opendkim[146]: DEB292A16D9: no signing table match for 'root@mail.domain.com'
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:52 mail opendkim[146]: DEB292A16D9: no signature data
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:52 mail postfix/qmgr[1898]: DEB292A16D9: from=<root@mail.domain.com>, size=283, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:52 mail postfix/smtp[1957]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4008:c04::1b]:25: Cannot assign requested address
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:53 mail postfix/smtp[1957]: Trusted TLS connection established to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.204.27]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:54 mail postfix/smtp[1957]: DEB292A16D9: to=<non-existence@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.204.27]:25, delay=4.2, delays=2.6/0.02/1.1/0.52, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.204.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [103.23.147.162] The IP address sending this message does not have a 550-5.7.1 PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from 550-5.7.1 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550 5.7.1 information. o7si2148670pgr.491 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:54 mail postfix/cleanup[1955]: 9185A2A16DB: message-id=<20171214021554.9185A2A16DB@mail.domain.com>
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:54 mail postfix/qmgr[1898]: 9185A2A16DB: from=<>, size=3010, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:54 mail postfix/bounce[1967]: DEB292A16D9: sender non-delivery notification: 9185A2A16DB
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:54 mail postfix/qmgr[1898]: DEB292A16D9: removed
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:54 mail postfix/pipe[1968]: 9185A2A16DB: to=<root@mail.domain.com>, relay=bounce-pipe, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via bounce-pipe service (20171214-021554))
mail    | Dec 14 02:15:54 mail postfix/qmgr[1898]: 9185A2A16DB: removed
```

The question is, where are bounced messages stored or how to pass them to my python script as parameter. Bounced messages should be formatted like this: https://github.com/sisimai/set-of-emails/blob/master/mailbox/mbox-0

Comment: Parse bounces how exactly, and for what purpose? For bounce tracking, you should be looking at VERP instead.

Comment: I want to collect information about bounces. And I have a database to store bounces information. The database, such as MongoDB stores data in JSON format. So, I need to collect bounces and convert it into JSON format, and then save it to mongodb

Comment: Another purpose, I want to sure that the success rate of sending emails this higher than 90%. I plan to send email to a list of email addresses. But, I want to have a high success rate of sending emails (i.e 90%). For example, I send an email to 1,000 addresses sequentially. If it reaches 100 bounces, I will stop it.

Comment: Sounds precisely like the use case for VERP. One of the reasons you can't reliably parse out the intended recipient from bounces is forwarding; another is that not everyone follows the RFC. I like to always mention Microsoft but it's not only them, though their bounces strike me as particularly useless.

Comment: @tripleee: VERP isn't the answer here. It simply returns bounces to a specific per-user address- what do you *then* do when you've got the email in an inbox?

Comment: @EML The question is rather vague; but if your question is, which address bounced, a well-constructed VERP encodes that information uniquiely so that it can be extracted and analyzed. What's the use case you have in mind?

Comment: @tripleee: collecting stats, analysing, blocking accounts, whatever. The identity of the destination mailbox is one part of the problem. The issue here is what to do when you've got 100s/1000s of bounces. Do you analyse them manually, or can Postfix help?

Comment: Postfix is just an MTA. I would write a Python script or similar to convert the bounces into machine-readable information.

Answer (score 1):

A well-formed bounce message contains a number of machine-readable headers.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message#Format for a brief introduction with hints for where to look for more information, including ultimately the pertinent [RFC 6522](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6522)

A bounce message is just a message. It is stored in the recipient's mailbox.  For example, if you attempt to send a message and it fails, Postfix will attempt to store the resulting bounce in your inbox, just like any other incoming message to you.

If you are only looking to automate processing of messages to a particular user (`root` or otherwise), Postfix already knows how to deliver to Procmail or Maildrop, both of which easily allow you to run arbitrary scripts on your incoming email, conditionally on message content (hint: look for the very specific DSN header fields from the RFC) or unconditionally.

Your question is very vague on what exactly you want to accomplish. For a start, you will need to understand basic MIME structure, including the concept of a "body part" and how each body part has its own set of headers and a (potentially empty) body (payload), and how these can be represented in a multitude of different content encodings.  The Python standard [`email` library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.html) was recently revamped; for new development efforts, make sure you target 3.6+ (though technically the new implementation was already present in 3.4, not just the default).

Comment: Thank for your response. I'm going to read the document that you gave me. But I have another question. When I receive a bounce, I want my script able to read the bounce content, analyze, and save it to another place (file, DB, etc,). So, I have to read all incoming message to check if it is a bounce, right?

Comment: Right; though as I hinted, Procmail or Maildrop could handle that part, and only pass messages with bounce characteristics to your script.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the question **How to pipe incoming email (message) to external program**,

I just simply configure aliases after installing postfix (/etc/aliases)

```
anyname: "| /tmp/your_external_script.sh"
```

And then renew aliases:

```
newaliases
```

If your script is a ruby program, then you can read all the incoming emails from stdin.

It looks like this:
http://davidsj.co.uk/blog/postfix-pipe-emails-to-a-script/

Answer (score 0):

The messages are given to your script by means of "stdin" (standard input).
Your script needs to exit with exit status 0 (since that signals a "successful delivery" to Postfix).

Comment: Hi Ralf - are you saying that the OP's proposed solution is a good way to process incoming bounces, with the stdin and exit status fixes? Would you recommend this?

Comment: I see no code here. I also agree with one of the comments here that VERP is the way better solution.